# Who was the general Ivan Tscherniakowski?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union

I have been reading Ian Kershaw's *Hitler 1936–1945: Nemesis*. At a certain point, he writes: “On 16 October, the ‘3rd White Russian Front’, led by General Ivan Tscherniakowski, had broken through into East Prussia as far as Nemmersdorf, Goldap”. Who was this General Ivan Tscherniakowski? I did a Google search, of course, but all the results seem to be related with Kershaw's book.

Comment: There's a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Chernyakhovsky) on him.

Comment: @SteveBird Thanks a lot. Kershaw wrote Tscherniakowski, not Chernyakhovsky. That's why I was unable to find anything about him.

Comment: You may want to keep in mind that there are [different ways to transcribe Cyrillic script in Latin letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script#Romanization), and perhaps familiarise with some of them, should the need arise again. In particular, the one with “tsch” to render Ч, in the place of “ch” or “č”, used to be preferred in German-speaking countries, so Kershaw might have derived it from some German source.

Comment: @SteveBird Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I never understood why so often people post answers as comments. I will surely mark it as the accepted answer if it appears as an answer.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Because the accepted standard here is to not to post answers that are easily found on Wikipedia (or similar references). Without having heard of this fellow before, I found the page in less than three minutes using just two google searches.

Comment: Actually, with all the sympathy for José, this is not even a question about history, but about different writing systems.

Comment: @DaG I know that *now*, but I thought that Ian Kershaw could perhaps have made some error.

Comment: @DaG: At one level, that makes the OP less "culpable," but at a different level, it makes the question more off topic.

Comment: Yes, @JoséCarlosSantos, that what I meant with the sympathy fact: it is clear that you meant to ask a question about a little-known historical figure.